# Read numpy file (.npy) without importing numpy or any other non-native import

Tags: python, numpy, import

***Note*** : by "non-native" import I mean import that need some kind of installation (like pip install) that wouldn't come naturally with python 2.7. I don't know if non-native is the correct term. Imports are fine, but no further installation should be required.

---

**Need** : I want to be able to **read a numpy file (.npy)** and retrieve the data within it **into a python list** or another python iterable.

**Constraint** : For ease of installation of my script, I'd like it to be **only native python**, requiring no further installation than just having python installed on the computer (so no numpy).

**Details** : the numpy file has been created by using [np.save](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) from the `numpy` library.

Side-note : For my problem, arrays are only `float` or `int`, but I guess it'll be nice to be able to read any type of array.

Comment: Why can't you use numpy though.

Comment: if you can't use `numpy`, you probably can't use `pickle` - and `*.npy` is a `pickle` (i.e. zipped) of the `ndarray` object by default.  That means you'd need to implement `pickle.load()`, `np.ndarray` and `ndarray.tolist()` into any "stand alone" reader to open it without dependency.  It's not likely worth it.

Comment: Just thinking out of the box: what about saving your data using `pickle` and `arr.tolist()`? That way you would be able to load it afterwards without external libraries. Otherwise, what about attaching TinyNumpy to your script? https://github.com/wadetb/tinynumpy

Comment: you can read the `.npy` file in using Pythons native file reading as long as you know the format of the data. The format is pretty straight forward and can be found [here](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html)

Comment: Thank you for all your intresting comments.
@BlueRine Because the usage of the script is through gimp as a plugin. The plugin is intended to be used by people with minimal computer knowledge, and we would like to keep the installation of the plugin as simple as possible. I've yet to decide whether it's worth it or not to go this way.

Comment: @norok2 Interesting way to skirt the issue. My array are images (400x600), wouldn't that'd be slow to load and would generate large files ?

Comment: @021 While in general this would depend on the hardware you will be running on, I would also say that such an object would amount to ~2K of data. I bet your Python script is larger than that, so if the interpreter can handle your script in meaningful times, it can certainly load that data similarly fast.